# js cross-domain to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have the iframe from different domain imbedded in my page. Is it possible to have access to its DOM from a parent page with some way?  Now it says:

---

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:63342" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

---

I hoped that adding the directive

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  ?>
```

to the iframe page will help, but it doesn't.
Both domains now are located on my localhost but under different servers running.
So is there some working solution?
Notice that I need just an access to some iframe's elements, it's not about postMessages, websockets etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice that I need just an access to some iframe's elements

Direct access is impossible

> it's not about postMessages

`postMessage` can achieve the same ultimate goal.

You just need to move the code which accesses the DOM to the page inside the iframe, and then use `postMessage` from the parent window to ask that page to run it. That page can then serialise any data the parent window needs to a string and use `postMessage` to send it back.

Comment: You see, I need the parent page to react immediatelly on events in the iframe. For example if user clicks *close* button within iframe, it should go down (i.e. going collapsed). If I understand right I can post a message from it to the parent page and run an appropriate procedure on it, but it will take some time, depending of connection speed, right?

Comment: *everything* takes time. `postMessage` doesn't take significant amounts of it (at least not on the timescales that UI updates take place on).